# Concatenar variable dentro de expresión

Tags: mysql, python, string

Estoy trabajando en Python y MySQL, tengo un query para insertar un registro, que se concatena con valores contenidos en una lista.

La función `cursor.execute(query,values)` procesa correctamente esta operación, sin embargo, es de mi interés obtener todo el QUERY ya concatenado como un string, para almacenarlo en un archivo de texto y no tengo mucha idea de cómo lograrlo. Acompaño un ejemplo:

```
query = "INSERT INTO factura_venta (id_factura,numero_factura_venta,cliente,fecha_venta,subtotal,iva,total,forma_pago,estatus_factura,es_xmayor,el_vendedor,que_sucursal)" \
                "VALUES(%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s)"
valores = ('null', x_num_fac, x_nombre, x_fecha, x_subtotal, x_iva, x_total,
           x_forma_pago, "OK", '0', que_usuario, que_sucursal)
```

La inserción en MySQL no es mi problema, sino que quisiera tener el query "ya concatenado" en un string para poder pasarlo a un archivo .txt  (para actualizar una base de datos remota  offline).

Comment: ¿Qué cliente estás usando en Python?

Comment: MySQL.connector propio de Mysql para python

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Si estas usando MySQLdb. Lo que buscas es la propiedad `_last_executed` del objeto `cursor` que estas usando, asi:

```
query = cursor._last_executed
```

Si estas usando MySQL Connector/Python (esta libreria la hizo MySQL directamente, asi que es mas recomendable usarla en lugar de MySQLdb). En mysql.connector se usa la propiedad [statement](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-api-mysqlcursor-statement.html) del objeto `cursor`, asi:

```
query = cursor.statement
```

Comment: Gracias Daniel por tu ayuda, es exactamente lo que necesitaba.

Comment: @Jaime Si mi respuesta solucionó tu problema podes marcarla como respuesta correcta a tu pregunta. Saludos.